# Integrating a program written in C with another one written in C++

Tags: c++, c, plugins, integration

I'm working on a project where I need to integrate 2 simulation software packages; as in the output from one is to be used as input for the other one, and vice versa. The exchange of information happens at every time-step of the simulation, so it occurs very frequently. Both simulation packages have support for plugins: one of them supports plugins written in C, and the other supports plugins written in C++. Is there an elegant way to integrate these two plugins to make the software packages talk to each other? I thought about reading/writing files to hard drive, but I'm hoping that there is a better way to do this.

Thanks all!

Comment: There's lots of ways to do [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is SOAP or RESTful service an option? That would work in both C and C++

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can use files to do that, but I wouldn't recommend writing them to the disk, but to use a [Memory-mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). There are several libraries that implement this functionality, such as [Boost C++](http://www.boost.org/). Java has the `FileChannel` class that handles it

Comment: Boost C++ looks promising for the C++ side of the project, but can it be implemented on the C side?

Comment: As for the name suggests, it's meant to be used with C++. However, you can use the OS native API in order to create and perform operations to memory mapped files. Both Windows and Linux have C APIs for that, that will work both with C and C++.